# Why were yesterday’s answers from me deleted and my account blocked?

Tags: discussion, support, account-suspension, feedback

I subscribed yesterday to address two unresolved threads about incremental site build technologies, for which I have subject matter experience in the field.

Can someone help me understand why my remarks were unwelcome?

As someone with a banned account, I cannot see how to post material to the "meta" site for Stack Overflow, which is why I am reaching out here.

[Changes-based regeneration by static site generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607287/changes-based-regeneration-by-static-site-generators)

The second one appears to have been deleted:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64834001/is-there-any-static-site-generator-that-supports-incremental-builds

I hereby grant Stack Overflow moderators/staff the necessary permissions to disclose the rationale for the 1-year suspension as an answer to this question.

HERE IS THE GARBAGE RESPONSE FROM TRUST AND SAFETY THREE WEEKS LATER. I HAVE NEVER CREATED ANY ACCOUNTS IN THIS HELLWORLD OTHER THAN joesuf4, WHICH WAS SUSPENDED.

Hello Joe,

While we understand the resolution was not what you expected, we re-affirm the response given above and consider the matter closed. We believe that the moderators acted reasonably and their guidance was sound in this instance. Further replies to this ticket will not be monitored and if you have a different matter you need help on, you can always raise a new ticket. New tickets for this specific situation will similarly be closed.

Best,
The Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange Trust & Safety Team

119571
On Mon, 8 Jan at 12:58 PM , Joe wrote:
Your lies are truly pathetic.

On Mon, Jan 8, 2024 at 12:41 PM Stack Overflow Support community-support@stackoverflow.com wrote:
Hello Joe,

I see your Stack Overflow account has been suspended due to a past violation of our Code of Conduct. We take such matters seriously in order to maintain a safe and respectful environment for our sites.

Upon review, it has come to my attention that there is an attempt to create a new account to circumvent the suspension. I want to emphasize that creating new accounts with the intention of evading a suspension is strictly prohibited on our platform. I understand that mistakes can happen, and encourage open communication to address any concerns or misunderstandings that may have led to the suspension. However, attempting to create a new account to bypass the suspension undermines the integrity of our community and violates our policies.

Instead of attempting to circumvent your suspension I encourage reaching out via these support channels to discuss the specific reasons for the suspension and explore the possibility of resolving any issues. In this case the original mod intervention has to do with spammer like behavior.

I hope this clears up some of the confusion regarding your suspension. As always if there is anything else I can help with please do not hesitate to contact us.

Best regards,
The Stack Trust & Safety Team

119571
On Sun, 24 Dec, 2023 at 3:04 PM , Joe wrote:
It’s been almost 7 days since:

1/ my pair of fully accurate posts were deleted,
2/ my account was eliminated.
3/ the replacement account assigned to me was suspended.

When can I expect the courtesy of an appropriate response that either justifies these actions or restores my original account (joesuf4)?

On Tue, Dec 19, 2023 at 10:53 PM wrote:
Thank you for your response.

On Tue, Dec 19, 2023 at 10:28 PM Stack Overflow Support community-support@stackoverflow.com wrote:
Hi there,

Thank you for writing to us – your ticket has been escalated to our Trust & Safety team. You should hear from them in the next few days, but it might take longer to get a response.
Please know that they’ll be working on it and will reach out if they have any questions or once there is a resolution.

All the best,
Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange Support Team

Comment: Without more information: No.  On top of that, you should have received a message in your inbox telling you exactly why you were suspended.  No one here can tell you that, aside from maybe moderators, and they normally won't do so through public channels.

Comment: Let me guess, you linked to your own blog/article/product that explains about the matter. Sadly, that is considered spam, even if overall helpful. Content is expected to come in the form of actual answer. (My assumption is based on the case your account was destroyed for spamming, as Sonic mentioned in a comment under the answer.)

Comment: You've been told what to do: Use the Contact Us option to get staff. You did so, now wait. Comments are not the place to demand answers to an already closed post. Nor are they the place to keep going on and on and on about the same thing.

Answer (score 17):

We cannot know. You were suspended on Stack Overflow for a year, but all it says is this:

> This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends on Dec 18, 2024 at 7:08.

With few exceptions, the reasons for the suspension aren't made public. You can explicitly tell a diamond moderator (or CM*) that they can make the details public, but otherwise, that's between you and them.

Speculation on suspensions is discouraged, but since you asked...

A year-long suspension isn't typically the result of a minor problem, but rather a repeated or extremely severe violation that was problematic.

If you post your remarks, we can give feedback, but... I'm guessing the suspension was for more than an innocent comment or two. Regardless, we cannot see those remarks, so it's hard to give meaningful suggestions there.

You should have (read: almost certainly) received a moderator message in your inbox that explains why you were suspended, though. You can reply (once) to that message, and then you can't reply again until a mod responds. If you feel your suspension was wrongly issued, you can [contact Stack Exchange staff](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https://stackoverflow.co) and appeal it, but moderators typically have good reasons when issuing a suspension.

---

*A CM is a Stack Exchange Community Manager, so SE staff.